# Why does VAT keep being added when editing payments

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

When we issue a membership the payment automatically feeds through the correct pricing.  If we then have to go in to edit the membership the price updates by adding VAT on again to the already inclusive total.  Has anyone else had this issue and how did you resolve it? We are using Civi 5.8.0.

Comment: Can you please edit this question to include your version of CiviCRM?  Do you have the [Line Item Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/line-item-editor) extension installed?

Comment: I'm not sure if we have the line item editor installed as the developer set it up for us, is there a quick way of checking this?

Comment: Go to Administer > System Settings > Extensions and look for it amongst the enabled extensions.

Comment: Thank you Joe.  Yes line item editor is installed and enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There was known bug up to CiviCRM 5.36. If editing the payment and there was an error, it re-applied taxes. https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/778